# C++ image encode / decode library

Tags: c++, image-processing, shared-libraries

I'm developing a scientific application for image processing. It uses it's own simple data type for storing images (pixel data, number of channels, etc.). What I need is the ability to read images of common formats (bmp, jpeg, png, maybe others), convert to my internal format and then export them after processing back to one of common formats.

I want this app to be as lightweight, as possible so I don't want to include "heavy" libraries, such as OpenCV or ImageMagick just for this one purpose.

Is there any simple, light and efficient c++ library just for encoding and decoding images of popular formats? Or the only option I have is to use separate libs, such as libjpeg and libpng, for each format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to open common formats, there are 2 ways: the separated libraries or, SOMETIMES, the operating system (you can open a JPEG with Windows API, for example).

There's no problem in using ImageMagick/OpenCV... they are very light! And even if you CONSIDER lighter to use the separated libraries, you will have to implement a common format of bitmap for you to obtain data from the output of each library (believe me, there are tricks here: number of channels, channels order, pixel order [from top-left to bottom-right], etc)... well, a lot of work!

So, why not use something already implemented like ImageMagick/OpenCV? All of this work is already done! I really believe this is a very good choice!

Comment: I was about to say that. Magick is lightweight, even if you are targetting low-end Android phones, for example. Apart from embedded applications (and you're running into different kinds of trouble there), there is really no performance- or space-related reason not to use Magick or OpenCV.

Comment: Well, my point was that the only thing I need from the library is to load and save images and with OpenCV or ImageMagick I have to carry a lot of code with my project, that is never used. But I don't want to reinvent the wheel, of course :) So maybe you're right and there are no lighter solution that would fit my needs. Thanks for your response!

Comment: You can get rid of some stuff of these frameworks (like all the effects of ImageMagick / the OpenCV machine vision functionalities) and have it lighter.

Answer (score 0):

Use FreeImage.

FreeImage is an Open Source library project for developers who would like to support popular graphics image formats like PNG, BMP, JPEG, TIFF and others as needed by today's multimedia applications. FreeImage is easy to use, fast, multithreading safe, compatible with all 32-bit or 64-bit versions of Windows, and cross-platform (works both with Linux and Mac OS X).

to download: http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/